# trouble setting up wiki family

Tags: mediawiki

I've installed MediaWiki 1.27.1 and managed to get a basic single-wiki setup working.  Now I'm trying to change it into a wiki family according to the instructions at [Manual:Wiki_family](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Wiki_family). Here's what I'm aiming for:

```
wiki.mysite.com/        #public wiki
wiki.mysite.com/priv1   #private wiki 1
wiki.mysite.com/priv2   #private wiki 2
```

The result I got:

`wiki.mysite.com` shows the public wiki, as expected.

`wiki.mysite.com/priv1` returns 404

`wiki.mysite.com/priv2` returns 404

[edit: added message text] The text of the 404 message:

```
Not Found

The requested document was not found on this server.
Web Server at mysite.com
```

What I did:

I followed the steps outlined in the manual, generated the 3 copies of LocalSettings.php, and renamed them. I then modified the main LocalSettings.php to the following:

```
<?php
if ( !defined( 'MEDIAWIKI' ) ) {
    exit;
}

## Database settings - cut-and-pasted out from the 3 sub-wikis' LocalSettings.php
$wgDBtype = "mysql";
$wgDBserver = "localhost";
$wgDBname = "db_wiki";
$wgDBuser = "db_wiki_user";
$wgDBpassword = "password";

$callingurl = strtolower( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ); // get the calling url
if ( strpos( $callingurl, '/priv1' ) === 0 ) {
        require_once 'LocalSettings_priv1.php';
} elseif ( strpos( $callingurl, '/priv2' ) === 0 ) {
        require_once 'LocalSettings_priv2.php';
} elseif ( strpos( $callingurl, '/' )  === 0 ) {
        require_once 'LocalSettings_public.php';
} else {
        header( 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found' );
        echo "This wiki (\"" . htmlspecialchars( $callingurl ) . "\") is not available. Check configuration.";
        exit( 0 );
}
```

For test, I've tried changing the file name in the `require_once 'localsettings_public.php'` line to each sub-wiki's `LocalSettings.php` file; when I open `wiki.mysite.com`, the related sub-wiki does get shown correctly.  The URLs with the subdirectory path continue to return 404, however.

Any idea what's wrong with my setup?

Comment: A 404 with what message?

Comment: the 404 text (edited question to include this):

    Not Found

    The requested document was not found on this server.
    Web Server at mysite.com

Comment: So it's not hitting your LocalSettings file. Some sort of web server configuration problem, then.

Comment: I've found that if I add a directory /priv1 and put, say, an index.html in it, then wiki.mysite.com/priv1 shows whatever is in this index.html.  As far as I understand, it's looking for the actual subdirectory, instead of going through the parsing code in LocalSettings.php (in the website root).  Is this a special behavior I need to configure in the server, and if so, what might it be called? (the server is Linux hosted on Plesk; I probably have to google a bit to find the related option.)

Comment: I think I found the problem: there's an update.php script that needs to be run; I misunderstood that step as optional.  Looks like I'll have to give up on this approach, since the hosting plan I have doesn't include command-line access.

Comment: You can run update.php from the web. Still sounds like a webserver configuration issue to me though. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL might help.